# Make function more Generic to save repeating

Tags: c#

I use the following function which is all well and fine but i basically do the same operation about 20 times. For various end points of an api I am hitting how would one make this routing more Generic in the ability to pass and return type  OF T.

```
public async Task<List<StockItem>>  GetStockDataFromSage()
{
        StockItem stockitems = new StockItem();
        string content = "";
        List<StockItem> result = new List<StockItem>();
        var uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constants.GetStockItems, string.Empty));

        var response = await _client.GetAsync(uri);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
             result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StockItem>>(content);

        }
        return result;

}
```

**Edit 1**

I am trying to use the below however I am getting an error

```
 public async Task<List<StockItem>> GetStockItemInfo()
 {
    return await dataTransfer.GetDataFromSageService(Constants.GetStockItems, string.Empty)) ?? new List<StockItem>();
 }
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1061  'StockTakeDT' does not contain a definition for 'GetStockDataFromSage' and no accessible extension method 'GetStockDataFromSage' accepting a first argument of type 'StockTakeDT' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  StockAppDL  D:\Git\Repos\StockApp\FStockApp\StockAppDal\StockDatabase.cs    76  Active

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your objective here appears to be to call an endpoint and get the results back into an object you can use.  If the call is successful, you return the result and if it fails, you return an empty list.

We can abstract that logic out into a generic method that accepts a url and parameters and returns an object.

```
public async Task<T> GetObjectFromEndpoint<T>(string url, params string[] args)
    where T : class
{
    var uri = new Uri(string.Format(url, args));

    var response = await _client.GetAsync(uri);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content);
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

Now your GetStockDataFromSage function passes in the information unique to this call, namely the url, parameters, and generic type for the results.  If the result is null, GetStockDataFromSage returns an empty list of StockItems

```
public async Task<List<StockItem>> GetStockDataFromSage()
{
    return (await GetObjectFromEndpoint<List<StockItem>>(Constants.GetStockItems, string.Empty)) ?? new List<StockItem>();
}
```

Any time you are trying to minimize repetition, you want to look at what is specific to this call and what is more general.  i.e `List<StockItem>`, the url, and possibly the parameter are unique, but the rest of the code is very general.

**Caution**: This method of returning a default value when the api call fails can lead to hard-to-diagnose issues where you will be unable to differentiate between an empty list and a failed api call.  I recommend adding some logging for failed api calls and perhaps looking at ways to inform the calling code that the result was in error.

Comment: Its a shame we cant dynamically name our funcitons to

Comment: its a interrnal service I am calling so i can send back what  ever what would you suggest as its a wcf service what would best way to handle that be